# What are the implications of the discovery of sterile neutrinos?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, neutrinos

In this Ars Technica [article we read](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/06/weird-neutrino-excess-wont-go-away-hints-at-new-physics/):

> Now Fermilab is back with its latest update, using two additional years of MiniBooNE data. The excess is still there, and it has edged even closer to the statistical standards for discovery. If you combine the Fermi and Los Alamos data, we're already there. It's looking more and more like another break in the Standard Model, and the possible explanations include an entirely new type of neutrino.

Some [have asked](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17272263) the question:

> Does this imply the existence of a new lepton?

My question is: **What are the implications of the discovery of sterile neutrinos?**